# WPF get parent of menuItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know how to get the parent of a menuItem? I searched all arround but can't get a good answer...

My XAML is:

```
<DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Right" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                <MenuItem Header="Devices">
                    <local:MenuItemWithRadioButton x:Name="MenuItemVideoDevices" Header="Video">
                    </local:MenuItemWithRadioButton>
                    <local:MenuItemWithRadioButton x:Name="MenuItemAudioDevices" Header="Audio">
                    </local:MenuItemWithRadioButton>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
</DockPanel>

private void MenuItemWithRadioButtons_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        if (mi != null)
        {
            RadioButton rb = mi.Icon as RadioButton;
            if (rb != null)
            {
                rb.IsChecked = true;
            }
            //Here I want to get the parent menuItem
        }            
}
```

In the code, when I click the submenuItem like "MenuItemVideoDevices", an event process function is triggered, but I don't know how to get the menuItem "Video" in this function.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

If you found that the `MenuItem.Parent` property is `null`, then your code is not as simple as what you posted. I put together the following simple XAML window, and it worked fine:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO16231375MenuItemParent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Right" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="2,0,0,0">
      <MenuItem Header="Devices">
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItemVideoDevices" Header="Video" Click="MenuItemVideoAudioDevices_Click"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItemAudioDevices" Header="Audio" Click="MenuItemVideoAudioDevices_Click"/>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

That is, the `Click` event handler can successfully retrieve the correct, expected `MenuItem` parent using the `Parent` property:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItemVideoAudioDevices_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

        MessageBox.Show("Parent's header text: " + ((MenuItem)menuItem.Parent).Header.ToString());
    }
}
```

Since you did not provide [a good, *minimal*, complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, I cannot say for sure why the `Parent` property was `null` in your test. However, I *can* say that in my own scenario (the one that led me to this question), the problem is that my child `MenuItem`s are template and so don't wind up with a non-null value in the `Parent` property. Note this comment in [the documentation for the `FrameworkElement.Parent` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For templates, the Parent of the template eventually will be null. To get past this point and extend into the logical tree where the template is actually applied, use TemplatedParent.

I found that following this advice was not straightforward. My `Parent` property was `null` from the outset. But so was the `MenuItem` object's `TemplatedParent` property *and* the logical parent (as retrieved by `LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()`).

What I wound up having to do was follow the visual tree up to find the first parent node that *did* have a logical parent. At that point, I was able to use that node's `TemplatedParent` property to retrieve the actual `MenuItem` parent.

I wrote a simple helper method to generalize this. So far, the only scenario I'm using it for is this `MenuItem` scenario, and I really don't know whether this is what would be needed in other cases. But it works for me and seems like a good starting point in case I run into a similar issue with other child object (or anyone else does).

Written as an extension method, it looks like this:

```
public static T GetTemplatedParent<T>(this FrameworkElement o)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject child = o, parent = null;

    while (child != null && (parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(child)) == null)
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }

    FrameworkElement frameworkParent = parent as FrameworkElement;

    return frameworkParent != null ? frameworkParent.TemplatedParent as T : null;
}
```

This allows me to retrieve the parent `MenuItem` object for any templated `MenuItem` object, without having to introduce any other objects (obviously I could have solved the problem just by initializing some static field somewhere and retrieving its value, but that's very hacky…I wanted something more general-purpose and reliable).

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is a simple example. Hope you find it helpful!

```
public void menuItemSelectionHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs rEvent)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem smi = sender as System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem;
    var parent = smi.Parent.GetValue(MenuItem.HeaderProperty);
    var child = smi.Header.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: This implementation of `MenuItem.LogicalParent` (which is *internal*) may help:

```
internal object LogicalParent
{
  get
  {
    return this.Parent != null ? (object) this.Parent : (object) ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer((DependencyObject) this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`MenuItem` has a Property `Parent`.

```
var parent = mi.Parent;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! but I found the mi.Parent is null! Does the "Parent" mean the parent menuItem?