# ContextMenuItem isEnabled binding to Object property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

I have a ContextMenu for TreeView items declared in the treeview:

```
<TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding countries, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myapp:City}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CityItem}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CityName}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Bisque"/>
                ...
```

And the ContextMenu itself declared as:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key ="CityItem"  StaysOpen="true" Foreground="Bisque">
    <MenuItem Header="Edit City"  CommandParameter="{Binding Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Click="EditCityClick"/>
    <MenuItem Header="DeleteCity" CommandParameter="{Binding Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Click="DeleteCityClick"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Well, at this point everything is working

```
private void DeleteCityClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    City city = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as City;
        ...
}
```

I can access to the city object, modify, delete, whatever and everything is updated in the gui acording to the changes in Cities and City properties (onpropertychanged is working fine).

The question is how can i disable a ContextMenuItem binding IsEnabled to a City object property? Let's say

```
public bool IsEnabled { get; set;}
```

I tried several ways, but idk how to access to the source object (City) from the ContextMenu MenuItem.

Thanks!

Edited: Sorry for the typo but:

```
public string IsEnabled { get; set;}
```

Actually is:

```
public bool IsEnabled { get; set;}
```

Edit 2:

Funny "not a wpf..."

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, why can't you simply use `SelectedNode` of the treeview? If the context menu is opened and one of the options is clicked, the `SelectedNode` cast to `City` should give you what you need. (And you won't need to use CommandParameter)

Comment: Actually I may be wrong, it is possible to right click a node without selecting in TreeView (I'm used to datagrids where that's not possible). Take a look [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/find-node-clicked-under-context-menu), its for winforms but converting to WPF should not be that difficult.

Comment: `sender` is `MenuItem`, [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16231375/1997232) to which `Menu` it belongs, then [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1884117/1997232) on which element menu is, then `DataContext` of this element is your `City`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't explain... I have no issues accessing to the City object... What i want is to bind the Isenabled property of the City object to the IsEnabled property of the MenuItem, i don't know how to bind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<MenuItem ... IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

It binds to the `DataContext` of the `PlacementTarget` of the parent `ContextMenu`, which should be a `City` object.

Comment: Is there such a Type of RelativeSource ContextMenu? ;)

Comment: Nope :) It should be AncestorType. Thanks for pointing this out. I edited my answer.

Comment: ... AncestorType is not a wpf ... <MenuItem ...
                      IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" /> neither works...

Comment: @Hüsk3rDü: Syntax error! See my edited answer and try again :)

Comment: If you put RelativeSource={AncestorType ContextMenu}} you get a funny error, see the screenshot above... You have to change it to RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"

Comment: Nothing yet, i will try another approach putting the contextmenu out of resources inside the treeview control...

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? The MenuItem isn't disabled or what?

Comment: @Hüsk3rDü It works for me for **MenuItem**.. Sure you have bool property, not a string? :))

Comment: It means that despite of the City IsEnabled value (set to false in the C'tor) the ContextMenuItem is enabled always...

Comment: @Rekshino yes, i double check it

Comment: @mm8 fixed with your code! I've changed so many things doing tests that i didn't realize that i moved IsEnabled... So, your code works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Hüsk3rDü Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for IsEnabled? You set it in C'tor of ContextMenuItem???

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is, that ContextMenu is in resources. So you can use PlacementTarget to get it bound.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key ="CityItem" IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Comment: Well, i don't need a converter since City object has a bool property called IsEnabled. On the other hand, i only want to disable one ContextMenuitem. I tried  <MenuItem Header="Delete City" CommandParameter="{Binding Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Click="DeleteCityClick" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/> with the IsEnabled property of City set to false, but still not working...

Comment: See my answer. Wrong type of ancestor. And you don't need a converter.

Comment: @ Hüsk3rDü Have you written in your question? public string IsEnabled { get; set;}

Comment: Not if you want to disable an individual MenuItem.

Comment: @Rekshino public bool IsEnabled {get; set;} is defined in City object...

Comment: @mm8 But disabled must be a ContextMenu, or? No, I think you are right: in question ContextMenuItem(therefore I was confused, there are either ContextMenu or MenuItem), in comment MenuItem

Comment: @Hüsk3rDü Then you have to ajust you question

Comment: @Rekshino, god... you're right... it's a simple bool, not a string, no converters needed

Comment: @Hüsk3rDü I have adjusted my answer. It works for (whole) ContextMenu, if you want it for MenuItem, then see answer from mm8